# Get already opened Edge (not IE) browser window(s) and scrape contents

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-edge

I used to be able to find all open IE windows via VBA and was able to access one of the already-opened page's contents in Excel with the objShell object mechanism. I didn't--and don't need--direct "control" (automation) of the browser in terms of pushing buttons, opening urls, etc.

I know automation of Edge is not possible just using VBA, but is there any ability to simply 1.) get a list of MS EDGE open windows and 2.) retrieve the elements within a given (already opened) window without resorting to downloading drivers and utilities like Selenium?

Comment: There's no COM interface to Edge, so I don't think you can do this from VBA without something like Selenium

Comment: AutoHotKey could be a good alternative

Answer (score 0):

As **Tim Williams** had informed you there is no COM interface available for the Edge browser.

Microsoft has not provided any way to automate the Edge browser using **VBA automation**.

So, there is no way to fetch the already opened instance of the Edge browser and retrieve elements with the help of VBA.

I suggest you use the officially recommended way **Selenium Web Driver** to automate the Edge browser.

I have seen that you want to avoid the **Selenium Web Driver** approach but at present, this is the only way available to automate the Edge browser.

If you are having any issues with the **Selenium Web Driver** approach then you can inform us about it. We can try to provide suggestions for it.

Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Please note: I'm the author of this software

You can connect to active instances of Edge with IE mode using Internet Controls for Edge: https://pomio.dk/internet-controls-for-edge/.

Internet Controls for Edge is a COM component and it exposes the same APIs as Microsoft Internet Controls (for Internet Explorer), so if you've already created some automations of Internet Explorer (using Microsoft Internet Controls), then it should be straight forward to move to Internet Controls for Edge.